# How to open Exo Platform in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, social-networking

I have installed Exo Community edition, and trying to figure out how I can develop my own portlet, change some part of the platform, create gadgets.

For that, I would like to open it with Eclipse. As far as I understood Maven is involved. luna comes with Maven as I can see.

Now the question: How can I open the Exo complete project in Eclipse?

Any other way of opening the project that would be easier/nicer I could consider?

Answer (score 1):

The projects of exo platform are under https://github.com/exoplatform/

But, if you want to develop a Portlet, you will not need to use the source project. All you need is:

1. Develop a portlet compliant to Portlet 2.0 Standard (JSR) (Example of portlets are [here](https://github.com/gatein/gatein-portal/tree/master/examples/portlets)! )
2. Add the WAR of your Portlet under Tomcat/webapps
3. Start the server if it's not yet started
4. Add your portlet inside a category of applications (follow this [link](http://docs.exoplatform.com/public/index.jsp?topic=%2FPLF41%2FPLFUserGuide.AdministeringeXoPlatform.ManagingApplications.ManagingPortletsAndGadgets.AddingPortletGadgetToApplicationList.html)!  )
5. Add your Portlet inside a page to dissplay its content ( follow this [link](http://docs.exoplatform.com/public/index.jsp?topic=%2FPLF41%2FPLFUserGuide.AdministeringeXoPlatform.ManagingPages.AddingNewPage.html)! )